# When the truth comes out about what happened in the past, should we judge them for it?

Tags: emes-truth-honesty

I work at a place that monitors and provides support for recovering humans who did foolish things.

How should a soul respond when the knowledge is afterwords gained that at a time a student did massively ungodly things thinking it would never be known ( or knowing the gravity of their offense was such or otherwise they may have not done it ).

Hashem's truth makes it so lies will never prosper.

Dealing with people I always must be respectful and loving, not judging, thereby providing the necessary mercy (for them) to change.

So, if a person was a little honest, but not completely (therefore deceiving), but living by their foolish ways committed a mutual act of fornication in a public place with no one looking, then got a certificate (of being good) because no one knew about what they did... but later on the truth came out and those sinners were living well off their ill gotten gains besides the fact.... how should we judge them?

Should I execute my thoughts towards their statements with acuity of an excellent judgement for what they've done under my jurisdiction or should I be lax and not regard their sins?

Is it ok to allow myself to lower my level of respect for those individuals and treat them in a way that is in accordance with their dishonest actions under my honest jurisdiction?

Or should I act like they never did such ungodly things just because I was not aware of it at the time?

That being said, I am (learning to be ) jewish and the sinners are not.

Thanks,
David

Comment: I VTC, the situation is very vague and very personal. This site does not deal with personal questions, like "should I ...". You better consult a Rabbi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have repented and are no longer doing the things they have repented of, then you are supposed to treat them as if their sins never happened. This is one of the most difficult things that a person can do, as it seems carrying a grudge comes more naturally.

But God asks us to forgive others in the same way that He forgives us, which is that once we repent He no longer remembers our sins. He asks us to forgive our fellow men in the same way. Inevitably we will be let down by those of whom we try to forget the sins of, and this can be a very painful experience. But just as God continues to forgive the people of Israel throughout the generations, we should strive to forgive those that we see have repented.